# Can't Login to StackExchange Because of Long URL

Tags: support, openid, login, myopenid

I cannot log into stackoverflow sites using my myopenid account because where I work they do not allow long URLs and very long URLs are passed back and forth between stackoverflow and myopenid.

I looked at the URLs in Fiddler and I noticed a 302 redirect to https://www.myopenid.com with 17 query parameters. I login by passing the following six parameters through (of the 17):

- openid.claimed_id
- openid.identity
- openid.return_to
- openid.realm
- openid.mode
- openid.ns

and it allows me through.

I work for the public sector (government) where they are paranoid about security and they tell me that they cannot allow longer URLs because it is a security concern (I don't believe them).

This trick **DOES NOT** work with Google which is also uses a redirect. Is there a way of logging in using in to StackExchange without being allowed longer URLs? Login on Mobile and transfer cookies? A means of tunneling? Changing URLs seen in Fiddler/WireShark? etc.

Thanks,
Tahir

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a proxy, but it sounds like your workplace wouldn't allow it. Another option would be to use an SSH tunnel to connect a PC at home, and forward your internet connection through that (more info on that [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/use-ssh-create-http-proxy), easiest if you have a linux PC at home), or by using a VPN to your home network for internet. Again, though, your workplace might not allow it through the firewall, since they wouldn't want government info going through outside networks. You should check with your IT people to make sure its OK (though if they're that paranoid, I'm suprised they don't have a filter blocking all but specific websites. Or do they?)

Comment: So essentially bypass the firewall. I'm fairly certain that most IT departments won't be happy if you do that

Comment: That's why i said to check. I don't think there's a way to do it without bypassing the firewall or using a different login method.